# Spring annotation to initialize a bean during Autowire

Tags: spring, spring-bean

Do we have a `spring annotation` that provides an option to initialize a bean (not a `component`) if not available through default constructor while `autowiring`?

If yes, that will be awesome. I am tired of initializing beans in some configuration class using default constructor and it occupies space.

I am doing this currently

```
@Bean
public Test test() {
    return new Test();
}
```

Expecting:

Sometime like:

```
@Autowire(initMethodType=constructor)
private Test test:
```

If no, was there no real need of such annotation or any technical limitation?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `@Bean` annotation inside an `@Configuration` class.

Check the following link

https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public TransferService transferService() {
        return new TransferServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Pavan, This is exactly what I am doing right now. My question is how to avoid this declaration and use an annotation which does bean initialization while autowiring. Let me edit my question to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

You could annotate your class with `@Component`, like this:

```
@Component
public class Test {
    ...
}
```

Whereever you need that class, you could then simply autowire it:

```
@Autowired
private Test test;
```

You would just have to make sure, that you use `@ComponentScan` to pick up that bean. You can find more information on that [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-scanning-autodetection).

Comment: What if it's not my class thats not a component. In my case, most of them are not.

Comment: In that case I don't think you have any other option, than using a central configuration class, like @Pavan suggested.

Comment: Updated my question. Will wait for more answers. Thank you.